# how to retrieve password/pin code from keyguard manager in android

Tags: android, authentication

Hot to get PIN CODE or Lock Screen Password using KeyguardManager ??

```
private static int CODE_AUTHENTICATION_VERIFICATION = 241;

  
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.ddddd);


        KeyguardManager km = (KeyguardManager) getSystemService(KEYGUARD_SERVICE);
        if (km.isKeyguardSecure()) {

            Intent i = km.createConfirmDeviceCredentialIntent("Authentication required", "password");
            startActivityForResult(i, CODE_AUTHENTICATION_VERIFICATION);
           
        } else
            Toast.makeText(this, "No any security setup done by user(pattern or password or pin or fingerprint", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }


    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && requestCode == CODE_AUTHENTICATION_VERIFICATION) {
            Log.d("IM ", "onActivityResult: "+requestCode);
            Log.d("IM ", "onActivityResult: "+data.get);
            Log.d("IM ", "onActivityResult: "+resultCode);
            Toast.makeText(this, "Success: Verified user's identity", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Failure: Unable to verify user's identity", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

It is part of the system's auth, you shouldn't be able to access the code itself as it would beat the purpose of it being secure... You only get a boolean if the entered code was correct or not. Getting the code itself is going into keylogger territory.